# in Swift/ CloudKit, what is the proper syntax for creating NSPredicate to search for double

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

Would any please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I am trying to use Cloudkit's `NSPredicate` to search for a Double value in the cloudkit DB and I'm not getting any results. No records come back when I know there should be some.  I feel that my syntax may be off. Any advice is welcome.

```
let val1: NSNumber = 5.4

let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "monday_start == %f", val1 )
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)

let combinedQuery = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate2])
```

Comment: Why are you creating a compound predicate from one predicate?

Comment: `%f` takes a Float or Double, not an `NSNumber`.